# Fish shell how to export current directory like in bashrc file

Tags: bash, fish

So I've changed to fish and I can't seem to export a variable like in bash let me show you:

In my ~/.bashrc file I have this:

```
export AIRFLOW_HOME="$(pwd)/airflow"
```

So when I launch `airflow info` command it goes for example to `/home/user/Documents/airflow`

Now with fish I saw that it was different and added to my `config.fish` this line:

```
set -x AIRFLOW_HOME "$(pwd)/airflow"
```

Now I'm still in my Documents folder but when using the airflow info command my folder is created in my `/home/user/`  directory also when I tried to do `set -x $TEST $PWD` even though I'm in a directory such as `/home/user/Videos/Shows/` it points back to `/home/user`

Does anybody know how I can achieve the results of bash but with fish?

Comment: BTW, even in bash, `$(pwd)` is a slow/inefficient way to do it -- consider `$PWD` instead, which doesn't require a fork for the command substitution.

Comment: ...that said, that `$(pwd)` is, again even in bash, relative to _where you are when your `.bashrc` is interpreted_, not where you are when you run the `airflow` command. If this question is asserting that in bash it's relative to the current location and you're trying to figure out how to do the same thing in fish... that's not how it works in bash. Try running (in bash) `cd /; declare -p AIRFLOW_HOME`; it won't be `/airflow` unless you've done extra configuration like a `PROMPT_COMMAND` hook or a wrapper around `cd` updating the variables.

Comment: `set -x AIRFLOW_HOME "$PWD/airflow"` or `set -x AIRFLOW_HOME (pwd)/"airflow"`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I already did with the $PWD also (sry I didn't mention it) still doesn't work let me try the one you suggested

Comment: @Cyrus set -x AIRFLOW_HOME "$PWD/airflow" I already tried and doesn't work

Comment: Which thing I suggested? I didn't give you any suggestion for fish; I only asserted that _even in bash, it doesn't work the way the question describes_.

Comment: Oh sorry I misread =.= in bash what I have works for some reason

Comment: So, that's the thing -- you're clearly doing something _else_ in bash that _makes_ it work; `export AIRFLOW_HOME=$(pwd)/airflow` doesn't have the effect you want, so you must have done something else that _does_ have that effect.

Comment: The point of `cd /` and then `declare -p AIRFLOW_HOME` is in part to figure out if the act of running `cd` (or printing a prompt after that successful `cd`) is what's doing the update, or if it's instead happening during `airflow` itself (in which case maybe you've got a shell function or an alias wrapping the actual airflow command).

Comment: ...once we know what you _actually_ did in bash (or what some airflow-provided file you're sourcing is doing, or so forth), then we might be in a place to start trying to figure out how to do the same thing in fish.

Comment: (maybe your bash scripts use `direnv`? That's another common way to set environment variables on a per-project basis).

Comment: For example in this link https://gist.github.com/userimack/4be186b5ce0d749bbc3a4033c5d8d9f1 
That person does the same thing as I found on some other searches just doing export AIRFLOW_HOME="<project_directory>" I don't really know why it works but after doing this when running airflow command they'll be all directed to that directory but I'm a big noob in bash stuff so I can't know

Comment: Right, an absolute path is fine, as you'd expect. It's `$(pwd)` that's a problem, because your dotfiles run _once_ when your shell initializing, so the assignment happens with whichever directory is current _right then_ and never gets rerun later when the directory changes.

Comment: Remember, inside double quotes (or an entirely unquoted context) expansions happen immediately; so in `var=$(pwd)`, the `pwd` command gets run and its output is substituted _before_ the variable `var` is assigned. There's no `$(pwd)` in the value that's set, so the `pwd` command is never run again; `var` keeps the value it had when that assignment was run.

Comment: So how would you do it so that it is persistent, so that every time I launch my airflow db init or something it creates the airflow folder in the directory I currently am and not always having to run the command export AIRFLOW_HOME="my/dir"?
I'm sorry if I seem dumb, it is because I am and also I never fiddled with bash

Comment: This hasn't been pointed out explicitly in the comments yet: fish command substitution is `(pwd)` without the "$", and command substitution does not happen inside quotes. `cd /some/directory; set -x AIRFLOW_HOME (pwd)/airflow` or use the absolute path `set -x AIRFLOW_HOME /path/to/airflow`

Comment: You're out of date, Glenn. Since fish 3.4, `"$(pwd)"` is indeed supported.

Comment: @glennjackman Sorry if I forgot to mention it. Also doesn't work with (pwd) it still points to /home/user/airflow instead of putting the absolute path for each project all I can do at the moment is, for each instances of fish on my vscode terminal to do export AIRFLOW_HOME="$PWD/airflow" with or without the quotes or parenthesis it still works but it was annoying to specify it every time I want to use an airflow command on a different terminal.
So all that is left for me is either only use bash when doing airflow projects or just do the export command every time I'm launching a new terminal

Comment: A temporary solution is just creating a shell script that'll export AIRFLOW_HOME to the current dir and launch the airflow commands and that's all but its a small workaround

Comment: As I said, if we know how you have it working in bash, _then_ we can figure out how to do the same thing in fish. For example, maybe you have `cd` wrapped in a function that updates AIRFLOW_HOME; or maybe you have an `airflow` shell function (or alias, or wrapper) in your bash config that sets `AIRFLOW_HOME` before running the real airflow command, or maybe... I could keep speculating forever; _only you_ have access to your machine to investigate how it's working.

Comment: I'll try to investigate further but It just reinstalled my OS so I didn't make any changes in bash or fish. All I did was launch a virtual environment in python pip installed apache-airflow and then ran the export command that they provide in this link https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.14/start.html
And then run the airflow commands